# Parsing XML to table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am using YQL to pull in a remote XML feed, I have this working in all other areas, but cannot get it to parse the data and format into a table. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3k7Tb/). The xml looks like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> 
    <BTCE>
        <TickerList />
            <Ticker> 
                <Average Value="" /> 
                <BuyPrice Value="443.95" /> 
                <Currency Value="USD" /> 
                <High Value="456.96" /> 
                <Low Value="424.00" /> 
                <SellPrice Value="444.27" /> 
                <Volume Value="18754.79784877" /> 
                <LastPrice Value="443.95" /> 
                <Time Value="04/28/2014 15:56:54" /> 
            </Ticker> 
            <Ticker> 
                <Average Value="" /> 
                <BuyPrice Value="444.32" /> 
                <Currency Value="USD" /> 
                <High Value="456.96" /> 
                <Low Value="424.00" /> 
                <SellPrice Value="444.70" /> 
                <Volume Value="18762.65028563" /> 
                <LastPrice Value="443.96" /> 
                <Time Value="04/28/2014 15:57:57" /> 
            </Ticker> 
            <Ticker> 
                <Average Value="" /> 
                <BuyPrice Value="444.32" /> 
                <Currency Value="USD" /> 
                <High Value="456.96" /> 
                <Low Value="424.00" /> 
                <SellPrice Value="445.00" /> 
                <Volume Value="18758.16227820" /> 
                <LastPrice Value="444.32" /> 
                <Time Value="04/28/2014 15:58:08" />
            </Ticker> 
        </BTCE>
```

I have the following HTML mark up:

```
<table class="fluid" id="BuyOrders">
    <tr>
        <th>Price per/ BTC</th>
        <th>Quantity, ฿</th>
        <th>Total, $</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Attempting to parse the xml like this:

```
$(function () {
    site = 'http://ec2-54-201-216-39.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/testc/WebService.asmx/GetTicker';
    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
    function loadTable() {
        $.getJSON(yql, function (data) {
            var xml = $.parseXML(data.results[0]),
            xmlDoc = $.parseXML($(xml).find("string").text()),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc),
            $buyPrice = $xml.find("BuyPrice");
            $volume = $xml.find("volume");
            $sellPrice = $xml.find("SellPrice");
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.length; i++){
            tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append('<td>' + $buyPrice.attr("Value") + '</td>');
            $('#BuyOrders').append(tr);
        }
    });
    }
  loadTable();
});
```

Comment: Why are you using .getJSON() to retrieve XML?

Comment: Was a workaround I found here on SO to get cross domain xml

Comment: Have you reduced this to the smallest possible bit so that you can insure that a.) XML is being returned and 2.) 'results' is part of the XML being returned?

Comment: Yes, i can get it with out the for loop and it will append to one td, I can't get it to loop through and create rows.

Comment: It appears that xml.length is undefined when I console.log() it.

Comment: I have it working so it is parsing and displaying the value, but its only doing one row, whereas there are mutltiple returned in the xml. However, when I console.log(xmlDoc) its only showing one. Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3k7Tb/2/ and if you hit the var site url directly you see multiple instances of 'Ticker' I think i got the wrapper screwed up somehow...

Comment: What should there be more than one of? All I see in this example are multiple Ticker's.

Comment: There should be a row with the specified values for each <Ticker> that is returned inthe xml, I am not getting multiple when I console.log but when I go directly to the var site URL you see there are mutlipel <Tickers>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51626/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-jay-blanchard)

Comment: I cannot chat from this computer :-/

Comment: No prob. I am tring to figure out how to run an .each function on the parse xml to find each instance of <Ticker> and parse its children and append them to a row. No joy.

Comment: I was working in that same direction

Comment: I found the issue - there is only one record in the XML that we are trying to retrieve in the fiddle, not multiples as you have shown in your sample above. http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/3k7Tb/5/

Comment: I had the wrong damn service. Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3k7Tb/6/

Comment: Happens to all of us - I didn't think to check the return until a few moments ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to loop over each `Ticker` in the xml and add a row for each one with the relevant values:

```js
function loadTable() {
    $.getJSON(yql, function (data) {
        var xml = $.parseXML(data.results[0]),
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML($(xml).find("string").text()),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);


        $xml.find("Ticker").each(function(){
            var buyPrice = $(this).find("BuyPrice").attr("Value");

            var tr = $("<tr/>");
            tr.append("<td>" + buyPrice + "</td>");
            /* ... any other tds here with various field values ... */
            $("#BuyOrders").append(tr);
        });
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3k7Tb/8/

Comment: I updated my fiddle with the correct service, http://jsfiddle.net/3k7Tb/6/ now returning multiple <Ticker>

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign  That doesn't change the code.  This code works with multiple:  http://jsfiddle.net/3k7Tb/8/

Comment: With the correct service and your example it works Thank you to you and @Jay Blanchard